# AddDataField removes field from "Report Filter"

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2010

Why does pivot table's AddDataField() method remove the field from "Report Filters"? I created a new pivot table using GUI and recorded a macro. All went well, except that the macro itself isn't working. How can I add a field to "Report Filters" and values with VBA (I'm only able to do it with GUI)?

Here's the macro I recorded. You can test running this on a blank sheet with A1 active. The last command removes the field from "report filters", even though everything worked fine while recording the macro and using the GUI. This really beats me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "foo"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R2C1", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R1C3", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(1, 3).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("foo")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("foo"), "Sum of foo", xlSum
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding data fields strips out all previously added fields and replaces them with those listed in your `.AddDataField` method. You must list all data fields you want in your `AddDataField` method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why AddDataField() removes the field from "Report Filter", but here are couple workarounds I found:

1. Use the GUI to add the field
2. Add the field to "Values" **first** and only then to "Report Filter":

   ```
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
       "PivotTable2").PivotFields("foo"), "Sum of foo", xlSum
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("foo")
       .Orientation = xlPageField
       .Position = 1
   End With
   ```
3. Use this sub that readds the field to "Report Filter" after it gets removed by AddDataField().

   ```
   Sub addDataField(table As Variant, field As Variant, name As Variant, fieldFunction As Variant)
       Dim orientation As Variant
       orientation = field.orientation
       table.addDataField field, name, fieldFunction
       field.orientation = orientation
   End Sub
   ```

   So the last command of the example should be changed into:

   ```
   'ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").addDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
   '    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("foo"), "Sum of foo", xlSum
   addDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"), ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("foo"), "Sum of foo", xlSum
   ```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I was mistaken. Open a new workbook, on Sheet2 in cell A1 type "label" and in B1 type "value". I then filled the first 50 rows of column A with either "a", "b" or "c", collectively my labels. Adjacent to the labels, I did a `RandBetween(1,50)`. The below code will output a PivotTable in cell A1 of Sheet1. I suggest playing with this to get a feel for how adding different fields works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub pt()
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb
    Set pc = .PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase,     .Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a2").CurrentRegion)
End With

With pc
    Set pt = .CreatePivotTable(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1"))
End With

With pt
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("label")
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("value"),,xlSum
    .AddFields RowFields:="label", PageFields:="value"
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You lost me here. Could you please give me a working example of using AddDataField() to add same field to "Report filters" and "Values" (sum function)?

Comment: A solution seems to be to add the field to "Values" first and only then add it to "Report Filter". I just don't understand why adding the field to "Report Filter" removes it from "Values". If I use GUI I can do it in either order, but in VBA I must do it in a specific order for it to work...

Answer (score 0):

@jumxozizi, you also need to set [`.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotfield-position-property-excel) in your 3rd workaround.

```
Sub addDataField(pv, ByVal field, Optional func, Optional caption)
    'Adds a data field to a PivotTable report preserving field's .Orientation and .Position
    'pv - PivotTable object, field - source field name
    'func - the function performed in the added data field
    'caption - the label used in the PivotTable report to identify this data field
    Set field = pv.PivotFields(field)
    orient = field.Orientation
    pos = field.Position
    If orient = xlPageField And Not field.EnableMultiplePageItems Then _
        current_page = field.CurrentPage
    pv.addDataField field, caption, func
    If orient = xlHidden Or field.Orientation <> xlHidden Then Exit Sub

    Dim lower_fields() As String
    ReDim Preserve lower_fields(pos To pos)
    lower_fields(pos) = field.Name
    'Temporarly hide group fields
    For Each f In pv.PivotFields
        If f.Orientation = orient Then
            f_pos = f.Position + 1 '-1 position after the `field` was hidden
            If f_pos > pos Then
                If UBound(lower_fields) < f_pos Then _
                    ReDim Preserve lower_fields(pos To f_pos)
                lower_fields(f_pos) = f.Name
                f.Orientation = xlHidden
            End If
        End If
    Next f
    'Add group fields back in right order
    For Each f_name In lower_fields
        pv.PivotFields(f_name).Orientation = orient
    Next f_name
    If orient = xlPageField And Not field.EnableMultiplePageItems Then _
        field.CurrentPage = current_page
End Sub
```

But because you set `.Orientation` first, your default `.Position` is the last one. This behaviour can cause pivot table overlapping with other content on the sheet. So in the above function I temporarly remove grouping fields which are "under" the `field`. Then I add them all back in the right order.

*Updated 2020-04-08: if field's `EnableMultiplePageItems=False`* then call to `addDataField` resets currently selected item (`CurrentPage`).